# react-native-firebase NullPointerException on android release build

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am getting below error in android when I have changed my MacBook. The app is running perfectly in the emulator/ real device. But I am facing this issue in making a release with **./gradlew assembleRelease** command.

```
A problem occurred configuring project ‘:react-native-firebase’.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I also tried the solution given on this [link](https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/493). But didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

After spending two days on this issue, I have found that there was a problem of Java version.

I added this two line in **gradle.properites**

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

And In Project Structure option -> SDK Location -> Enable Use embedded JDK

This solution is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make release build from android studio.

Before doing that go to android folder and run `./gradlew clean`

Follow below steps:

Open you project in android studio and search for `build` -> `generate release apk` -> `follow steps for keystore and all` then select release option at last window.

Comment: hey, thank you for your reply. But this solution didn't work for me.